# Tweaking react lazy loading webpack output to combine two webapps

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

We have a React Webapp where every route is lazy loaded:

```
const HomeScreen = React.lazy(() => import('../components/HomeScreen/HomeScreen'));
```

This, as expected, generates various JS files during a production build:

- main.js
- 1.main.js
- 2.main.js

Is there any way to load those generated production code in another Webapp we have?
Do they simply replace the content of a specific DOM element? and if so, how do they go about it?

Comment: Extra notes by author: clearly tweaking generated code does not seem like a good practice. However, under our circumstances of having a bundle created by legacy code, if possible, it could prove to be a good intermediate solution for combing new code with legacy code on a routing level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Module Fedration for this
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/microfrontends-module-federation-exposing-remote-from-legacy-react-webpack4-created-by-f3753d70d34e